# jQuery to make the input text field readonly

Tags: jquery, mobile, text, input, readonly

I'm using jQuery mobile and I have an input text field that is auto selected when tapped/clicked using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.highlight').click(function(){
         var input = this;
         input.focus();
         input.setSelectionRange(0,999); 
     });
});
```

I would like to add something to prevent changes to the field because I tried adding `readonly="readonly"` to the HTML but it stopped the auto highlight (on mobiles).

Any suggestions?

Comment: [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.preventDefault)

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I use it in my case?